# xDebug session cannot be invoked by stream_socket_client

Tags: php, xdebug

I have 2 wordpress installations on my computer. One installation is a server type and invokes  other with stream_socket_client function on port 80. When I put breakpoint on client side and make debug session in eclipse, this part of code is executed, but the xdebug debugger cannot be stopped at the breakpoint. I do not have same problem when invoke the same request with curl.

I use Mac OS, but have the same problem on Linux.

My xdebug configuration is:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug_remote_log
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=on
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s.%t
xdebug.collect_return=on
xdebug.collect_vars=on
xdebug.auto_trace=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

At first, it should be enabled multisession in xdebug option in eclipse.

The second, it should be added the following line in request header:

```
Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=ECLIPSE_DBGP;
```